# win32 api semaphores - blocked queue

Tags: winapi, semaphore

fellow programmers :-)

Is there a way to know if any thread is blocked on the specific semaphore (queue isn't empty), using win32 api and c++?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about waiting on the semaphore with at timeout?  If the timeout fires, immediately lock the queue and check the count.  This will only give a rough guide - it's posible for a producer to enqueue an object netween the timeout and locking the queue, but it might enable you to debug your P-C queue.

Comment: How do you check count of win api semaphore? I couldn't find such function... 
I don't need this for debuging purposes, but i need to solve starvation in readers-writers problem, that i have in my program, so i have to check if any writers are blocked and waiting...

Comment: Sorry, I meant the queue count.  IIRC, ReleaseSeamphore() can return the previous count - might be useful.  What problem are you getting whith what kind of queue?  I've not seen any problems with Windows semaphores and I use them a lot for counting/blocking producer-consumer queues.

Comment: I don't have any problem with semaphores, I just need to synchronize readers and writers properly so there is no starvation of any... So when a reader requests to read, he must check if there is a writer that is currently writing, or if there is a writer in a waiting queue (blocked on a semaphore), and if that is case reader must stay blocked on an other semaphore...

Comment: Similar is with writer... To interpret that algorithm into code I need a function that checks if there is anything blocked on a semaphore (a part where I check if there is any writer waiting), so I need smtg like a function that would return semaphore count, and if it's negative it means there is a writer waiting, or smtg like that...

Comment: It seems to me that you are using the semaphores incorrectly if you see any need to check anything.  A blocking, bounded producer-consumer queue needs two semaphores and a queue lock - it's an absolutely standard multithreaded comms mechanism that's been around since Dijkstra. One semaphore, 'A' reflects the count of objects in the queue, the other, 'B' the number of empty slots.  Readers wait on 'A', then lock the queue, pop an object, unlock the queue and signal 'B'.  Writers wait on 'B', lock the queue, push an object, unlock the queue and signal 'A'.  No checking required.